# Apache POI color cells in Excel using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to give a background color to the heading row of my Excel but the below code does not work. Can someone help.

Edit 1
Below is the full code for reference. The heading text overwrites the background color and even if I set the color to LIGHT_BLUE the Excel has black as the background.
[image]

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

```
    XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
    style.setFont(font);

    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("WIP E-MCAD Development");
    Row row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("Javatpoint");
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    //style=row.getRowStyle();

    Row rowhead = spreadsheet.createRow(1); //header

    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    ((XSSFFont) headerFont).setBold(true);

    rowhead.setRowStyle(style);

    rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Wire");
    rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Device From");
    rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Pin From");
    rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Device To");
    rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Pin To");
    rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue("Wire Level");
    rowhead.createCell(6).setCellValue("HRN Level Alias");
    rowhead.createCell(7).setCellValue("Option Code");
    rowhead.createCell(8).setCellValue("Feature Description");
    rowhead.createCell(9).setCellValue("Option Code Status Message");
    rowhead.createCell(10).setCellValue("CAN LIN Status");



    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        SoniResponse data = list.get(i);

        row = spreadsheet.createRow(i + 1);

        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(data.getWire());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(data.getDevice_From());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(data.getPin_From());
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(data.getDevice_To());
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue(data.getPin_To());
        row.createCell(5).setCellValue(data.getWire_Level());
        row.createCell(6).setCellValue(data.getHrn_Level_Alias());
        row.createCell(7).setCellValue(data.getOption_Code());
        row.createCell(8).setCellValue(data.getFeature_Description());
        row.createCell(9).setCellValue(data.getOption_Code_Status_Message());
        row.createCell(10).setCellValue(data.getCAN_LIN_Status());

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to set the fill pattern on the style as follows:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Note `XSSFCellStyle` vs. `CellStyle` in the original code: Only `XSSFCellStyle` allows to set the style using the `FillPatternType` enum.

Then you also need to actually set the style on the header row:

```
rowhead.setRowStyle(style)
```

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#setRowStyle-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle-

Comment: Its still not working even after adding the above line.

Comment: @prathibha I did update my answer to also explain how to set the fill pattern

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. One more question, even if I set LIGHT_BLUE the Excel has black background and text overwrites the background, have provided a screen shot, any idea why?

Comment: @prathibha you should try `style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());` instead (as shown above). Afaik the fill background is used as the secondary color in case you use a fill pattern and has no effect for `SOLID_FOREGROUND`.  I don't see why the formatting does not work in the second row, it looks a bit like the cell style is different for some reason and takes precedence over the row style.